# JavaScript button function result after page reloading

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a login and register modal and these modals share one same attribute, so I wanted to create an onclick function for each of the modals' submit buttons to trigger errors in respective modals. I tried this code to see if the button can trigger for the modals to show,

```
function loginModal(){
            $('#modal-register').modal('show');      
   }
    
   document.getElementById("modal-login-btn").addEventListener("click", loginModal);
```

and it does, however it only works before the page reload, as when i click the submit button, the page will reload. I want the modal to show after the page reload. I also tried this but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        function loginModal(){
            if (count($errors) > 0){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#modal-login').modal('show');
                });
            }        
        }
    });
    
    document.getElementById("modal-login-btn").addEventListener("click", loginModal);
```

Does anyone have any idea how to make the function run after page reload?

Comment: If you're using jQuery you should be doing `$("#modal-login-btn").click(loginModal);` instead of `document.getElementById("modal-login-btn").addEventListener("click", loginModal);`.

Comment: Why are you using a mix of native JS like `getElementById` and `addEventListener`, and jQuery?

Comment: Why are you calling `$(document).ready` twice?? It'd be helpful to show some HTML.

Comment: @code ah because previously i tried $("#modal-login-btn").click(loginModal); but it didnt work for some reason, i tried it again but below the function and its working now. however the result still occurs before the page reload. also regarding the double $(document).ready, i thought putting it before the function would make the function run after the page load.

Comment: You can try using a cookie to do so. Check the cookie on page load, then show the modal if the cookie string contains a variable value.

Comment: Could you show some HTML? Also, if you're already in a `$(document).ready` a nested one will do nothing besides complicate things up.

Comment: @Andy im still not very well-versed in JS so that was a result of me trying and error the codes and solution i found on the Internet, however i found out i could also make $("#modal-login-btn").click(loginModal); work by putting this line after the function.

Comment: @Heewoon would you mind to elaborate more? like do i not need to use an onclick button function and try to show the modal using cookie instead?

Comment: @code will the html for the modal button suffice or would you like to see the HTML for the whole modal? also noted regarding the $(document).ready, will try not to make the same mistake in the future. also to clarify why I used it twice, it was because I thought fitting it before the function would make the function runs after page reload, figured out it doesn't work that way though.

Comment: Oh, okay. As Heewoon mentioned, you can use a cookie, or more easily [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). On page load check the local storage to see whether, e.g. `localStorage.get("showErrorModal")` is `true` or `false` and display it based on that.

Comment: @code alright will try now thank you! will get back if there are any issues or confusion!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GET value at the url of the page when the page reload:

1. you can set the url in javascript at the moment of reload

**for example**

window.location.replace(window.location.href+"?reloaded=true");

2. implement a function who detect if the url contains a reload GET
   value.
3. if the GET value exist, show the modal directly.